# JSF2 commandButton action execution order

Tags: jsf-2

I have an input field with Ajax functionality on a `blur` event and a commandButton on my page.  If I modify a value on my input field and click the commandButton without tabbing out, which method will be called first?  The listener attached to the input field or the button?

From my experience so far the one that is called first varies, which is causing some issues in my application. I would like the listener for the input field to always be called first.

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the responses and after troubleshooting a little more I noticed that as has been mentioned the ajax listener is called first but on rare occasions the button action is called before the listener method has finished processing some desired logic. In my case, I need the listener method to finish processing before the button action is called otherwise some unexpected behavior may occur. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: The explicit javascript runs first on the page.Ajax is JavaScript version of `XHR` request so when you specify a event it will get executed first.You can check the example here http://jsfiddle.net/pgrUk/. Even If you enter some text and click on button `blur` alert come first and on second click `button` alert comes.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that everything in JSF is converted back to HTML and JavaScript.  Therefore a simple test as such :

```
<input type="text" id="field1" onblur="blurFunction();">
<br/>
<button onclick="clickFunction()">Click</button>
```

Will show you what you need to know.  With the tests I have done, `blur` comes up first.

If you are having issues with this, why not have a simple check when clicking your button to make sure that whatever needed to run on `blur` was run?

#### Edit

As per the edited question, you could always set a flag on your `blur` event.

```
function blurFunction() {
    document.myVar = 1;
    //... rest of the function
}

function clickEvent() {
    if(document.myVar = 1) {
        //wait
    } else {
        //do your click event
    }
}
```

It is not suggested to put your variable in the global scope.  This is just but an example as to how this can be done.